# Will rsync preserve owner between servers if the username is equal but the userid is not

Tags: permissions, rsync

I have the following case:

Server A has a user `marco` with userid `10001`
Server B has a user `marco` with userid `10004`

I'm copying a file `test.txt`, owned by `marco`, from server A to server B, with `rsync -avz` running on server B as `root`.

Will rsync preserve the owner if the userid is different?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes and no.

- If you're a *normal user* on server B, rsync cannot do anything about file ownership – all files created by you will be owned by you, end of story. Thus, if you're connecting to server B as "marco", the files will be owned by "marco" (10004).
- If you have root privileges on server B and don't use any special options, then rsync will preserve the *username* – files will be owned by user "marco", no matter what UID it has.
- If you have root and use `--numeric-uids`, rsync will preserve the *UID* – files will be owned by UID 10001, no matter which user it belongs to.

Comment: Great. I forgot to mention I'm root on both server. So when the man of a tool use the word "owner" it means "username", it's right?

Comment: rsync -a option includes -o that in man is described as "preserve owner"

Comment: No, it can mean either. Such tools as rsync or tar usually have an explicit option to switch between "preserve owner UID" and "preserve owner username" modes. Since rsync has `--numeric-uids`, it implies (and is mentioned in the manpage) that the default is to send textual usernames.

Comment: It's now `--numeric-ids` (at least `rsync version 3.1.2`).